# Solving system of quadratic congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, number-systems

If you have a system ex:

$ab \equiv 1 \mod 9$

$ab \equiv 3 \mod 10$

$ab \equiv 10 \mod 11$

$ab \equiv 7 \mod 12$

is there a way to determine integers $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "No" - you can use the Chinese remainder theorem to find the equivalence class of $ab \pmod{d}$, where $d$ is the lcm of your moduli, but you cannot find the values of $a$ and $b$ individually.

For example, the congruence $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ has several solutions, as does $ab \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$. You can deduce that $ab \equiv 73 \pmod{90}$, but there will be many possible pairs of values for $a$ and $b$ which will make this true.

Comment: Is there a way to use trial guessing or something of that sort?

Comment: If you look at $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$, you can take $a$ to be any number which is not equivalent to $0 \pmod{9}$, and then find a value of $b$ which works.

Comment: Does increasing the number of congruencies decrease the possible ab?

Comment: *i mean pairs (a,b)

Comment: And is there an algorithm for determining all the possible pairs (or a general solution to the number of pairs)

Comment: This is getting a bit long-winded. Maybe it would be better for you to try an example or two and then post another question?

Comment: Assuming $ab$ and $d$ are relatively prime, $a$ could be anything relatively prime to $d$, and then $b \equiv (ab) a^{-1} \mod d$.

Comment: Is there an online textbook or something on this particular topic?

Comment: I don't know about any in particular, but if you Google for "solving congruences modulo", you will get many possibilities.